# What does assignment like x\y = 1 mean in Julia?

Tags: julia

While experimenting with Julia 1.0, I've noticed that I can do something like this:

`x\y = 1`

The REPL then shows:

`\ (generic function with 1 method)`

which means its a valid assignment (the interpreter doesn't complain). However, `x`, `y`, and `x\y` all remain undefined.

What is the meaning of such expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a new function **definition** that (kind of) shadows the left division operator `\` in `Base`, since the left division operator is already defined for some types in Julia. The new function definition is `\(x,y) = 1` (the names of function parameters do not matter) which works for all types of variables. This will prevent julia from loading `Base.\` due to name conflict. No matter what the input is your new `\` will return the same value.

```
julia> x\y = 5

julia> a = 3; b = 4;
julia> a\b
5
julia> c = "Lorem ipsum"; d = "dolor";
julia> c\d
5
```

If you have already used the `\` that is defined in `Base`, your redefinition will throw an error saying that extending `Base.\` requires an explicit import with `import Base.\`. The behavior of defining `\` after `import Base.\` however will be different. It will extend the operator `Base.\`.

```
julia> 1\[1,3]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 3.0

julia> import Base.\

julia> x\y=3
\ (generic function with 152 methods)

julia> 1\[1,3]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 3
```